# Error while deleting worksheet from a Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I need to delete some sheets from an Excel workbook in C#.

But, my code does not work.

```
    // **aDeleteList** hold the sheets that need to be deleted from the workbook wbk
    static void delete_sht(ref MsExcel.Workbook wbk, List<string> aDeleteList)
    {
        MsExcel.Sheets my_st = wbk.Sheets;
        foreach (MsExcel.Worksheet s in my_st)
        {
            if (aDeleteList.Contains(s.Name))
                s.Delete();
            int t1 = my_st.Count;
            int t = wbk.Sheets.Count;
        }
    }
```

The values of t and t1 do not change no matter

```
          s.Delete()
```

has been executed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Removing while iterating can be a bit tricky.  You are iterating through s and trying to delete s also.  Something like this should work a bit better

```
static void delete_sht(ref MsExcel.Workbook wbk, List<string> aDeleteList)
    {
        MsExcel.Sheets my_st = wbk.Sheets;

        for (int i = my_st.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            if (aDeleteList.Contains(my_st[i].Name))
                my_st.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: you could try my_st[i].Delete();

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete from an underlying collection while iterating in `foreach`. Use a `for` loop instead.
[From MSDN :](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

> The **foreach** statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object collection that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface. The foreach
>   statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the
>   information that you want, **but can not be used to add or remove items
>   from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects**. If you
>   need to add or remove items from the source collection, **use a for
>   loop.**